# Move qemu window output over the network to catch it with another PC

Tags: networking, operating-system, partitioning, qemu, arinc

I have an application written in C which uses qemu and its output is continuously displaying itself on the qemu window.

Now what I want is to get this output over the network.
I need some changing in the overall command of qemu. I have read the documentation.

But it is not happening the way I want.

Comment: Can you provide some code that you have written? And also describe what exactly works in an unexpected way.

Comment: actually i have been working on POK which is a rtos for implementing arnic653 api.i didnt provide the code because its not just one c file all other files for partitions are generated.So thats why.just a simple question what command changings are to be don when you want to send the output of qemu over the network